# Assign value if string is whitespace?

Tags: c#, sql, string

I have a SQL command in C# that gets the manager field from a database like such:

```
SELECT manager FROM table WHERE number = '123456'
```

I then add it to a list like such:

```
c.Manager = Convert.ToString(sdr["manager"]);
```

I eventually add the result to a table. My problem is that in the database sometimes there is  no entry for the number does not exist or the manager is just a string of whitespace.

How could assign the value " - " to c.Manager in these cases?

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing the real issue, but don't you just need an `if` to see if the `manager` exists or is empty??

Comment: the real problem is when there is no entry for that number in the database, the table displays no rows instead of a blank row or anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your title. Please see, "Should questions include “tags” in their titles?", where the consensus is "no, they should not". http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test for the value to see whether it's null or whitespace.

There's a handy built-in method in the `String` class:

```
var manager = Convert.ToString(sdr["manager"]);

c.Manager = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(manager) ? "-" : manager;
```

Comment: this takes care of the whitespace, but still if manager is a string for an entry that does not exist it does not fix the problem. . .it still displays no row at all instead of "-"

Answer (score 0):

```
c.Manager = Convert.ToString(sdr["manager"])==""?"-":Convert.ToString(sdr["manager"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a single line if statement

`c.Manager = (Convert.ToString(sdr[@manager@]) == "") ? "-" : Convert.ToString(sdr["manager"]);`

Answer (score 0):

How about you tell your SQL script to return '-' instead of a whitespace or Null?

SELECT
     CASE WHEN manager IS NULL
                     OR LTRIM(RTRIM(manager)) = '' 
                THEN '-' 
                ELSE manager
     END AS manager
FROM table
WHERE number = '123456'

Benefit - Avoids data manipulation in C# code. Also keeps further changes easier and you can now simply assign the value to c .Manager.

NOTE - I firmly believe that if any data manipulation like the one in your case needs to be done, should be done while generating the resultset for better maintenance sake at least.